# EditText inside floating Activity not updating immediately upon typing

Tags: android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity (be it Act.A), and it starts another activity (be it Act.B) which floats above Act.A, with the following style set:

In Act.B's onCreate(savedInstanceState):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoTitle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

In Act.B, there is a fragment which has an EditText. In the fragment's onActivityCreated, I show the soft keyboard using the following lines of code:

```
edittext.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(edittext, 0);
```

Here is my xml for the EditText

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:fontFamily="fonts/avenir-light.ttf"
                android:hint="@string/sms_send_code_number_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="@color/sms_verification_edittext_grey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
```

The soft keyboard is shown, and the cursor is inside the edittext. Yet upon pressing keys on the soft keyboard, the edittext does not update immediately. Only after i dismiss the soft keyboard by pressing the Back button, would the edittext be updated with the correct text.

I also notice that other UI in the fragment does not update immediately when the keyboard is shown. Yet the UI would be updated when I dismiss the soft keyboard.

Any hints would be highly appreciated. thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating further, I found it is not related to the above codes.

The problem is due to the custom linearLayout for customizing a round corner around the edges which contains the edittext. So it works fine after I implemented another method for drawing round corners.